# Having great difficulty implementing login system using SQLite in Java

Tags: java, database, sqlite

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    String query;
    boolean login = false;
    String username = jTextField1.getText();
    String password = jTextField2.getText();
    try{
    query = "SELECT (cUsername AND cPassword) FROM Customer WHERE cUsername = '"+username+"' AND cPassword = '"+password+"'";
    pst = conn.prepareStatement(query);
    pst.setString(1, username);
    pst.setString(2, password);
    pst.executeQuery();

    String userCheck = rs.getString(1);
    String passCheck = rs.getString(2);

    if((userCheck.equals(username)) && (passCheck.equals(password)))
    {
        login = true;
        System.out.println("It actually works?!");
    }
    else
    {
        login = false;
        System.out.println("Psyche, that's the wrong number!");
    }

    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }

    System.exit(0);

}
```

I'm currently having difficulty implementing a login system in my code. I'm trying to retrieve the text from username and password jTextFields and then query them to the database but it's not working. At the moment I'm getting

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
```

and I unfortunately have no idea why. Any help would be GREATLY appreciated.

Comment: shouldn't the query be `select cUsername,cPassword`, like `query = "SELECT (cUsername , cPassword) FROM Customer WHERE cUsername = '"+username+"' AND cPassword = '"+password+"'";`

Comment: where did you define `rs` ?

Comment: and shouldn't there be a `ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery()`?

Answer (score 2):

Your query and the logic behind got a lot of work to do:

First of all, if you want a parametrised query, you must use '?' instead of the value. Then the pst.setString will work.

Secondly, you must affect the `pst.executeQuery();` to a `ResultSet`

```
query = "SELECT cUsername, cPassword FROM Customer WHERE cUsername = ? AND cPassword = ?";
pst = conn.prepareStatement(query);
pst.setString(1, username);
pst.setString(2, password);
ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();

if (rs.next()) {   
   String userCheck = rs.getString(1);
   String passCheck = rs.getString(2);
}
```

Comment: Many thanks for your help. Now I'm getting java.sql.SQLException: ResultSet closed and unsurprisingly I'm not sure why.

Comment: I think I just figured it out I did this         while (rs.next()){
        userCheck = rs.getString(1);
        passCheck = rs.getString(2);
      }

Comment: Edited to add this rs.next (I forgot it)